# How to make node.js function asynchronous? still returning empty object sometimes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have an object in my Node.js route (`result`), and I want to split that into two separate objects and return them both. However, sometimes the second object is returned empty and to fix that I want to make the function that splits it asynchronous. For some reason its not working though, what am I doing wrong? The function is `separateResult()`.

EDIT: The problem seems to be in my `createResponse(rows`) function. My SQL query always returns 6 rows but my `createResponse(rows)` function sometimes returns an object with 5 key-value pairs instead of 6.

```
function createResponse(rows) {
  var response = {}
  var random = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
    response[random] = rows[i].user_name
  }
  return response
}
```

Comment: There's nothing _asynchronous_ inside `separateResult` function. Remove the `async` keyword and call the function like you would call any other synchronous function. Also don't `await` the call to this function.

Comment: I did that and the problem still remains. I open up localhost:3000 and high is empty sometimes, and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: Log the `result` object and observe its value when `separateResult` function returns unexpected value.

Comment: Its empty, I'm pretty sure that res.send happens before the separateResult function can finish that's why high is empty sometimes. I believe the solution is to make the function asynchronous, I just don't know how to do that exactly.

Comment: What value of `result` are you passing to `separateResult` function as a parameter?

Comment: An object with 6 key value pairs

Comment: Include it in your question.

Comment: Sorry I included it now

Comment: I meant post the object literal in your question.

Comment: Are you sure that here `high[numbers[5]] = users[5]`   `numbers[5]` always exists.? Looks like sometimes it does not exist

Comment: I am adding an entry to the empty high object there.

Comment: Oh you are right I think, I just console.logged it and numbers[5] is undefined when high is empty

Comment: Ok I found the problem.. for some reason my result object is sometimes only 5 key-value pairs, even though the query is `SELECT user_name FROM USER_NAMES LIMIT 6`

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOB Hey brother, any chance you can help me out? I have identified the problem and edited the question. My createResponse() function sometimes returns with 5 key-value pairs instead of 6. I think because its returned before the for loop is finished. Can you help me make it callback-based function or using promises to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Math.random()` sometimes generates same result. This can be any time 4/10, 3/5 ... anytime. Think of finding another way of giving key names to your response. E.G. you are using a loop. So `i` is always different. You can do `response[rows[i].user_name+i]`. Best practice would be using  `uuid` library

Comment: thank you so much brother, you are so smart! May Allah reward you. this was the solution. I fixed it by making the keys be the usernames (since they are all unique) and the values being the random numbers.